# Range and the mysteries that it covers going out of my range

Tags: ruby, range

I am trying to understand how `range.cover?` works and following seems confusing -

1. `("as".."at").cover?("ass") # true` and `("as".."at").cover?("ate") # false`

   This example in isolation is not confusing as it appears to be evaluated dictionary style where `ass` comes before `at` followed by `ate`.
2. `("1".."z").cover?(":") # true`

   This truth seems to be based on ASCII values rather than dictionary style, because in a dictionary I'd expect all special characters to precede even digits and the confusion starts here. If what I think is true then how does `cover?` decide which comparison method to employ i.e. use ASCII values or dictionary based approach.
3. And how does range work with arrays. For example -

   `([1]..[10]).cover?([9,11,335]) # true`

   This example I expected to be false. But on the face of it looks like that when dealing with arrays, boundary values as well as `cover?`'s argument are converted to string and a simple dictionary style comparison yields true. Is that correct interpretation?
4. What kind of objects is `Range` equipped to handle? I know it can take `numbers` (except complex ones), handle `strings`, able to mystically work with `arrays` while `boolean, nil and hash` values among others cause it to raise `ArgumentError: bad value for range`

Comment: Which version of Ruby you use, because I can't replicate your output using Ruby 1.9.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Why does `([1]..[10]).cover?([9,11,335])` return `true`

Let's [take a look at the source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/a251302038d8b4c98d220c4f9843786fb9d8dd10/range.c#L904). In Ruby 1.9.3 we can see a following definition.

```
static VALUE
range_cover(VALUE range, VALUE val)
{
  VALUE beg, end;

  beg = RANGE_BEG(range);
  end = RANGE_END(range);
  if (r_le(beg, val)) {
    if (EXCL(range)) {
      if (r_lt(val, end))
        return Qtrue;
    }
    else {
      if (r_le(val, end))
        return Qtrue;
    }
  }
  return Qfalse;
}
```

If the beginning of the range isn't lesser or equal to the given value `cover?` returns `false`. Here *lesser or equal to* is determined in terms of the [`r_lt`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/a251302038d8b4c98d220c4f9843786fb9d8dd10/range.c#L147) function, which uses the `<=>` operator for comparison. Let's see how does it behave in case of arrays

```
[1] <=> [9,11,335] # => -1
```

So apparently `[1]` is indeed lesser than `[9,11,335]`. As a result we go into the body of the first `if`. Inside we check whether the range excludes its end and do a second comparison, once again using the `<=>` operator.

```
[10] <=> [9,11,335] # => 1
```

Therefore `[10]` is greater than `[9,11,335]`. The method returns `true`.

## Why do you see `ArgumentError: bad value for range`

The function responsible for raising this error is [`range_failed`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/a251302038d8b4c98d220c4f9843786fb9d8dd10/range.c#L26). It's called only when `range_check` returns a `nil`. When does it happen? When the beginning and the end of the range are uncomparable (yes, once again in terms of our dear friend, the `<=>` operator).

```
true <=> false # => nil
```

`true` and `false` are uncomparable. The range cannot be created and the `ArgumentError` is raised.

On a closing note, `Range.cover?`'s dependence on `<=>` is in fact an expected and documented behaviour. See [RubySpec](http://rubyspec.org/)'s [specification of `cover?`](https://github.com/rubyspec/rubyspec/blob/356fa4fb3e40/core/range/cover_spec.rb#L42).

Comment: Excellent answer. Just that true <=> false #=> nil pisses me off. Every dumbass knows that true is greater than false :)